# After Filter redirects to login.jsp, proper servlet doesnt get called

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

My simple project structure is shown in [this link](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/161/projectworkspace.jpg). I am using Eclipse and Tomcat 6.

There is `login.jsp` which submits its form to `login_servlet`. The `login_servlet` sets a session variable and then redirects to `home.jsp`. The `home.jsp` file has links to the 4 JSP files under a directory called `/sam`. In `web.xml` I have given the `url-pattern` as `/sam/*` for the `LogFiler` filter.

The `LogFilter` just reads the session variable and does `doChain(request,resposne)` if valid, else it redirects to `/login.jsp`.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Basically I don't want anyone to access files inside `/sam` directory directly. Now let's say, I try to directly access a file inside `/sam` directory, the filter kicks in and the redirection to `login.jsp` works and even the broswers contents are that of `login.jsp`,  but the url in the browser doesn't change. When I enter details and press submit, instead of sending the data to `login_servlet`, it sends it to `sam/login_servlet` and then tomcat tells me there is no such servlet here! Obviously there isn't. My doubt is why is it sending it so `sam/login_servlet` instead of `/login_servlet` which is usually what it does when I start running the `login.jsp` on my own.

One more thing, is there a way I can apply the servlet to ONLY `.jsp` files inside `/sam` diectory? I tried giving the `url-pattern` like `/sam/*.jsp`, but Tomcat was refusing to accept that `url-pattern`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually *forwarding* the request, not *redirecting* it. You normally use [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to forward the request and response to resources which aren't directly accessible by URL and thus you want to hide their location from the browser address bar. You normally use [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) to redirect the response to a **new** request, which thus get reflected in the browser's address bar.

Replace the forward in the `doFilter()` as follows:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
```

As to your second question, unfortunately that's not possible. You'll either provide a more specific and compatible `url-pattern` like `/sam/pages/*` or to let the servlet check the request URL.

Comment: wow thank you very much!it worked. 

i just changed it a little...
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/<project-name>/login.jsp");

thanks!